# Rails 6 - undefined local variable when passed to a partial but it is defined when I put a debugger in the erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm passing a collection to a partial:

```
<%= render partial: "discount_rule", collection: @programs.discount_rules, locals: { f: form } %>
```

the local variable `f` is successfully passed to the partial.

I print out the local variables available to me in the partial:

```
<%= pp local_variables %>
```

The result I get is:

```
[:local_assigns, :output_buffer, :discount_rule, :discount_rule_counter, :discount_rule_iteration, :f]
```

I'll add a debugger:

```
<% debugger %>
```

type in `discount_rule` in the terminal and get the correct object that has a field `name`.

I replace the debugger with:

```
<%= discount_rule.name %>
```

So it's in the same scope as the debugger was. I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `discount_rule' for #<ActionView::Base:0x000000000078c8>
```

There are no syntax errors. I have also tried `discount_rule_counter` and `discount_rule_iteration` and renaming the variable name from the collection (using as: :variable_name) and get the unknown local variable or method errors. I have tried not using collections and just rendering the partial and passing the variables in an each loop. Same errors. What am I doing wrong?

This is a Rails API only app that I had to change things slightly to have one page.

Comment: have you tried using `local_assigns[:discount_rule]`?

Comment: @FelixOuttaSpace you are my favorite person right now!

Comment: Feel free to answer the question and get the points

Comment: cool that it helped!

Comment: Can you show what { f: form } is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using `local_assigns[:discount_rule]` to access the local variables.

one could use `collection: @programs.discount_rules, as: :discount_rule` as well and call `discount_rule` in the view.

At the same time make sure that the data is not nil in your controller and that you are able to print the required attribute like name before passing it to partial with something like `.each do |instance| p.name`

Comment: So close. I celebrated too soon. I'm able to see the discount_rule object when I use `<%= local_assigns[:discount_rule].to_json %>`. But I am still unable to access any of the fields like `<%= local_assigns[:discount_rule].name %>` saying that it's nilClass even though `<%= local_assigns[:discount_rule].class %>` returns DiscountRule. Do you think this is a rails 6 bug? Should I report it?

Comment: try to use as here maybe it helps, so it would be `collection: @programs.discount_rules, as: :discount_rule` and now you wont have to use local_assigns here. you are able to just call `discount_rule`. I don't think that it is a rails bug, I used this successfully within similiar cases

Comment: maybe check in on controller level on your data as well, to make sure that it is not nil there. so when it already is nil there then the error is something else.

Comment: I have tried `collection: @programs.discount_rules, as: :discount_rule` before with the same results. I know that discount_rules is not nil. I am able to see the json object with local_assigns[:discount_rule].to_json. I just can't seem to do anything with it

Comment: ok this sounds strange, not sure why it is still nil can you print out discount rule names on the view before the partial? doing something like `.each do |dr| p dr.name` so if it a problem with passing you should be able to render the names in the view in which you call the render

Comment: Yes, I am able to print out the variable's names on the main page before the partial

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239995/discussion-between-ksc-and-felixouttaspace).

Comment: Created an issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43826